# Python чтение из Serial

Tags: python, serial

Не могу понять, как прочитать разное кол-во символов из `serial`.

Пытался использовать такой код:

```
import serial
import time

port = serial.Serial(port = "/dev/ttyAMA0", baudrate = 115200)

def serial_read():
 cde = 't\r'
 port.write(cde.encode('ascii'))
 print port.read('кол-во символов')
```

если кол-во символов/букв, в слове "`Привет`" = 6, и в `print port.read()` мы ввели `6`, то мы прочитаем их все, если `5`, то только `5` букв, если `7`, то Python ждет дополнительного символа/буквы. Как заставить, `Python` сам считать их кол-во.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по всему, вы используете pyserial. Попробуйте port.in_waiting для получения числа символов во входном буфере. А потом читайте то количество, которое в буфере есть.

Comment: не могли бы вы приложить пример такого кода?

Comment: @Insider не мог бы. Как минимум, мне не на чем проверить, да и код элементарный.